# view and scene not correct on iOS device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, skview

When doing a rotation, I'm getting an out of place view/scene. The viewWillTransition method is as below:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
  let newRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
  let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height)

  self.view.frame = newRect

  let skView = self.view as! SKView      
  if let sceneNode = skView.scene as! GameScene? {      
    sceneNode.size = newSize

    sceneNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY)

  }
}
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to update the view frame size, auto layouts adjust view frame automatically when you rotate device. if you want to update subviews frame in View use the "viewWillTransition" method and do frame changes accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        if let sceneNode = skView.scene as! GameScene? {
            sceneNode.size = self.view.frame.size

            sceneNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx @AshokPolu!
I prefer this because the size will be animated along device rotate animation.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(in: self.view, animation: { (_) in
        if let skView = self.view as? SKView, let scene = skView.scene as? GameScene {
            scene.size = self.view.frame.size
            scene.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY)
        }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```